# Passing data from mysql to html using ajax in django

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, django

I have a problem to transfer data from views.py to html using ajax `get` method. I get correct json object from models.py in views.py, but javascript function `ShowStores` does not connect ourstores.html and views.py. I even do not see any output from ShowStores.js. Here is the code:

models.py

```
class Supermarket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def ourstores(request):

    stores_list = Supermarket.objects.all()

    response_data = serializers.serialize('json',stores_list)

    return HttpResponse(response_data,content_type="application/json")
```

ShowStores.js

```
function ShowStores() {

console.log("show stores is working");

$.ajax({

    url : "ourstores/",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(response){

        $("#show_stores").html(response);
        console.log(response);
        console.log("success");

    }

    }); 

};
```

ourstores.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class='col-sm-12' style='text-align:center'>
<h2>Check out our stores:</h2>

 <div id="show_stores" align="center" onload="ShowStores()"></div>

 </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think you can not render the data obtained with js with django tags. Try rendering the obtained json with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I cannot even see any output from ShowStores.js.  So I cannot see why ShowStores does not trigger.

Comment: What is `console.log(response)` printing?

Comment: It does not print anything just like console.log. I tried to invoke ShowStores when DOM is ready but it is the same.

Comment: Can you try with `Supermarket.objects.all().values('name', 'address', 'city')` and see what `console.log(response)` prints.

Comment: It throws the error: **'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'**.

Comment: Use json.dumps instead serializer and send just data you need.

Comment: I tried, it does not work without serializer.

Comment: Can you show me your url definition?

Comment: It is this:  `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$','shoppire.views.home',name='home'),   
    url(r'^thank-you/$','shoppire.views.thankyou',name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^about-us/$','shoppire.views.aboutus',name='aboutus'),
    url(r'^our-stores/$','shoppire.views.ourstores',name='ourstores'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: This line I care `url(r'^our-stores/$','shoppire.views.ourstores',name='ourstores'),` I think there is where you wanna point to. Then in `url: "ourstores/"` I see an error, it should be `url: "/our-stores/"` or `url: "{{ url 'ourstores' }}"`

Comment: Still does not work. I am not sure whether this response is in ok format that I got from view.py: `[{"fields": {"city": "Helsinki", "country": "Finland", "name": "K-market", "address": "Kilpolantie 16"}, "model": "shoppire.supermarket", "pk": 1}, {"fields": {"city": "Helsinki", "country": "Finland", "name": "S-market", "address": "Kontulankari 16"}, "model": "shoppire.supermarket", "pk": 2}]`. Maybe javascript has a problem to recognise this.

Comment: So you get that json from the ajax process? But it is not html, `.html()` function won't load it as html. `console.log(response)` prints that json? BTW, it is in the rigth format, I tested it with a json parser and with `json.loads()` python method.

Comment: I get this from `HttpResponse` in views.py. OK so I have to find a way to parse the response as a json not as a html. I will try with json.parse. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try with a function that build an html from a json. I am happy to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning JSON from the view, not HTML, so you can't simply pass the JSON returned to the `.html()` method from jQuery an expect it to automagically render the JSON to HTML.

Instead, you'll need to use something like Underscore's [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to render each item in the array of objects returned.

Also, Django has a built-in [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), so you don't have to form up your own.

Alternatively, you can always render the HTML server-side and pass it back to jQuery, but depending on the size of the payload coming back, this may be more or less efficient.

I would also invoke `ShowStores()` when the DOM is ready via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowStores();
});
```

instead of inlining it in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried with JsonResponse but it is the same. The problem is here actually that ShowStores does not trigger.

Comment: I updated the example code to call `ShowStores` on DOM ready.